# Which is preferred, “… on 2010 or later …” or “… on or after 2010 .…”?

Tags: word-choice, syntactic-analysis

Which of the following is preferred?  Does it matter?

> Any person born on January 1, 2010 or later, is entitled to ...

or

> Any person born on or after January 1, 2010, is entitled to ...

Comment: The latter. (Although it’s not a very strong argument, the former could be viewed as ambiguous.)

Comment: user302366  is correcg and please notice that the details you posted do not correspond to the actual Question. "on 2010 or later…” and “… on or after 2010…" are simply wrong, and can't be compared to "on January 1, 2010 or later" nor to "on or after January 1, 2010".

If that doesn't make sense please, why not?